# Android - How to fix Rupee symbol font icon to the left of EditText

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want an EditText with rupee symbol fix at left side of the EditText.
[image]

**Note:** It is a floating labeled EditText. I have used `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`. And when I am deleting the text inside EditText, all the text should be cleared except Rupee symbol.

I want to use Rupee font string `<string name="rs"> \u20B9 </string>` instead of rupee png file.

If it is recommended to use only rupee png file, then we can use `drawableStart`. But how to control the size of that icon?

I need suggestions.

Comment: you can convert png file to svg file and use as vector drawable.

Comment: `onTextChanged` must do the trick.

Comment: Even when I use vector drawable, then with "drawableStart" how to control the size of the icon?
I want to put the icon always for the editText (not only on textChanged).

Comment: Attach, rupee string as a prefix on `onTextChanged(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate drawable at runtime. Below is the code to generate drawable

```
public Drawable getSymbol(Context context, String symbol, float textSize, int color) {
    Paint paint = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    float baseline = -paint.ascent(); // ascent() is negative
    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(symbol) + 0.5f); // round
    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.5f);
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(symbol, 0, baseline, paint);
    return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), image);
}
```

Now pass the values like this.

```
Drawable drawable = getSymbol(context, "\u20B9"/*Your Symbol*/, editText.getTextSize(), editText.getCurrentTextColor()); // This will return a drawable
```

To set this drawable to your EditText, use this code

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
```

Comment: It is not working for me. Will it work with TextInputLayout (for floating label)?

Comment: set it to your EditText.

Comment: I am setting to EditText only.

Comment: Nothing is visible on my EditText field.

Comment: This is a tested code. It works fine in fragment. Check the values of textSize, width and height in getSymbol(). Try changing symbol to some string.

Comment: Thanks @satish. It is working fine. Earlier I was used password field. For password field, it is not coming.

Comment: How to give paddingRight to the symbol? so that there should be some gap between symbol and entered text.

Comment: Just give space in the string. Like this `"\u20B9 "`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code :

```
      ediText.setText(getText(R.string.rs) );
      Selection.setSelection(ediText.getText(), ediText.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use do this with icon. but if you don't want to use icon for that here is the trick

try this Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="\u20B9"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="18dp"
        android:text="500" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

### EDIT :

If you still wanna use icon for that. you can generate icons from [Actionbar Icon Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=add_circle&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_add_circle&theme=light&color=rgba(33%2C%20150%2C%20243%2C%200.6)), copy all icon to desire folders, and rest you know :D

### EDIT 2 :

with `TextInputLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="\u20B9"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/f_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Amount"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result :**

[image]

Happy Coding..

Comment: My requirement is to have EditText in TextInputLayout (for floating label). But your answer is for non-floating label EditText.

Comment: It will Work for floating label too... just wrap EditText with TextInputLayout

Comment: I tried it already. When I use TextInputLayout, underline is shifting to right side of the rupee symbol. I want the symbol to be part of EditText.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get Rupee symbol from String resource file
String mTextInitial =getText(R.string.rupeesymbol);
```

Use this symbol as the initial value of `EditText` in Activity/Fragments directly

```
mRuppeTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(!s.toString().startsWith(mTextInitial)){
                    mRuppeTxt.setText(mTextInitial);
                    Selection.setSelection(mRuppeTxt.getText(), mRuppeTxt.getText().length());
                }
            }
        });
```

Now user will not be able to edit/delete the `mTextInitial` value assigned to `EditText`

Comment: I implemented the same. But when I try to clear the textbox, I am getting below error.
Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 77633(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 4(33MB) LOS objects, 12% free, 107MB/123MB, paused 1.412ms total 152.199ms
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Comment: Try putting some dummy value than R.string.rupeesymbol and try. String mTextInitial =" ABC ";  And test if its giving error or not. I not sure about how  .UndeclaredThrowableException is relevant to this code...